# How to flush the authentication cache in JBoss EAP 7

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

We are migrating an application from JBoss 4.2.1.GA to JBoss EAP 7. 
We want this to flush authentication cache. The earlier application used the MBean "jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager" which isn't available in EAP7 JMX.

Some help needed.

Thank you.
Regards,

Comment: 1.Login to the jmx-console: http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/
2.Scroll down and find this domain: jboss.security
3.Click on the MBean: service=JaasSecurityManager
4.Scroll down and invoke this method: void flushAuthenticationCache() that takes a String which is the security domain you want to flush

Comment: To programmatically flush the entire cache, use the following code:

MBeanServer server = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss(); 
String jaasMgrName = "jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager"; 
ObjectName jaasMgr = new ObjectName(jaasMgrName); 
String domainName = "name"; //for example "jmx-console" 
Object[] params = {domainName};
String[] signature = {String.class.getName()}; 
server.invoke(jaasMgr, "flushAuthenticationCache", params, signature);

Comment: To remove only one user entry from the cache, use the following code:

MBeanServer server = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
String jaasMgrName = "jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager";ObjectName jaasMgr = new ObjectName(jaasMgrName); 
String domainName = "name"; //for example "jmx-console" 
Principal user = new SimplePrincipal("username"); 
Object[] params = {domainName, user}; 
String[] signature = {String.class.getName(), <br /><br /><br />Principal.class.getName()}; 
server.invoke(jaasMgr, "flushAuthenticationCache", params, signature);

Comment: To change the default authentication cache timeout:

Edit $JBOSS_HOME/server/$JBOSS_CONFIG/conf/jboss-service.xml
Search for org.jboss.security.plugins.JaasSecurityManagerService
Then change the value of DefaultCacheTimeout (Default is 1800 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

for the standalone mode only the JMX-Objectname has changed from EAP4/5 to EAP7...
for domain mode you can't use the jmx subsystem. You need to call the jboss-cli (can be called programmatically too).

```
MBeanServerConnection mbeanServerConnection = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("jboss.as:subsystem=security,security-domain=" + domain);
mbeanServerConnection.invoke(mbeanName, "flushCache", null, null);
```

you can use jconsole (or any other jmx-management tool) to explore other mbean signatures..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the cache type to infinispan and add auth cache expiration/eviction,you can use following Jboss-CLI commands:
`/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=security:add()
  /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=security/local-cache=auth-cache:add()
  /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=security:write-attribute(name=default-cache, value=auth-cache)
  /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=security/local-cache=auth-cache/expiration=EXPIRATION:add(lifespan=120000, max-idle=60000)
  /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=security/local-cache=auth-cache/eviction=EVICTION:add(strategy=LRU, max-entries=1000)
  /subsystem=security/security-domain=exampleSecurityDomain:write-attribute(name=cache-type, value=infinispan)`